# Wrong path after loadURL

Tags: electron

I'm trying to navigate to another page within my electron app. For some reason, `require('./src/auth-renderer.js')` in `auth.html` points to the invalid path after navigation is complete. Any ideas why?

I have the following folder structure:

```
|- src
|-- auth.html
|-- auth-renderer.js
main.js
index.html
renderer.js
```

My code:

```
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))

  mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'src/auth.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true
    }));
  })
```

auth.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <script>
        require('./src/auth-renderer.js')
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have u tried `./auth-renderer.js`? (as you are in auth.html there)

Comment: @pergy yes, it errors out on initial load. `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './auth-renderer.js'`

Comment: How about `<script type="text/javascript" src="./auth-renderer.js"></script>`?

Comment: This works, thanks! I'm wondering why...

Comment: idk my first suggestion works for me, and that's reasonable